# I got a Samsung Galaxy 3 lite from a friend I don't have the Google accounts info and don't know the password to unlock

Tags: pattern-lock

Samsung Galaxy 3 lite
Please I got it from a friend that moved away. I don't know the Google accounts info or the password or pattern to unlock it. What do I do??

Comment: You stop stealing people's locked and probably encrypted phones

Comment: Just ask your friend. Is it that hard to do so?

Comment: There are thousands of tutorial on how to bypass FRP on Samsung devices. If it is not the FRP, just reset the phone to the factory.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the IMEI number written under the battery !

Give me that number and I'll see if i can help !